# OpenGL compute level of detail

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew

i've tried to render some Lines to a texture and then mipmap them. But when I scale down the whole thing it is not as low detailed as I want to. How can I achieve a lower resolution of the Texture? I tried a triangle with a little bend. So when I scale down like 50% it shall look like a normal triangle. Is there anyway to render it like this? Since I have really low experience with OpenGL I will post you the whole code.
Version:
Glew 2.1.0
OpenGL 4.6

Code:

```
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("BA", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1920, 1080, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    vertices.push_back(Vertex{ -0.5f,-0.5f });
    vertices.push_back(Vertex{ 0.0f,0.8f });
    vertices.push_back(Vertex{ 0.0f,0.8f });
    vertices.push_back(Vertex{ 0.0f,0.5f });
    vertices.push_back(Vertex{ 0.0f,0.5f });
    vertices.push_back(Vertex{ 0.5f, -0.5f });
    vertices.push_back(Vertex{ 0.5f, -0.5f });
    vertices.push_back(Vertex{ -0.5f,-0.5f });



    GLenum err = glewInit();

    //Framebuffer
    GLuint FramebufferName = 0;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);


    //Texture
    GLuint renderedTexture;
    glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);
    

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    /*glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2, GL_RGB, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, GL_RGB, 128, 128, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);*/

    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    float borderColor[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, borderColor);


    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0);

    // Set the list of draw buffers.
    GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
    glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);
    glViewport(0, 0, 1920, 1080);


    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(struct Vertex, x));

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, 1920, 1080);


    glScalef(0.9f, 0.9f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    

    bool closeFlag = false;
    while (!closeFlag) {


        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vertices.size());

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

        /*GLenum error = glGetError();
        std::cout << "Error: " << error;*/

        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                closeFlag = true;
            }
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN) {
                glScalef(0.95f, 0.95f, 1.0f);

            }
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_UP) {
                glScalef(1.05f, 1.05f, 1.0f);
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:
[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whgnx.png)

Desired output:
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sm6k.png)

Comment: Wouldn't [this](https://imgur.com/a/FhWDhXY) be the desired output?

Comment: What you want to do has nothing to do with mipmapping (at least in general). What you want is some geometric level of detail, and this is something you have to implement yourself, there is no magic GL function which automatrically does what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read the description of [glGenerateMipmap](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml).
For a deeper understanding of mipmapping and how it is implemented: [OpenGl Specification 8.14.3 Mipmapping](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#subsection.8.14.3)

In order to reach (see) your desired result, you would have to zoom more out. Down the way, there could be a reduced image, which is what you expect.

Fine-tuning of texture filtering can be accomplished via [glTexParameter](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml) and the different parameters like:

- GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL
- GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS
- GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER
- GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER
- GL_TEXTURE_MIN_LOD
- GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOD
- GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL

You could also generate the mipmaps yourself via [glTexStorage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml) and [glTexSubImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml) but this requires two texture objects and multiple render steps (render reduced image into texture A, upload into specific level of texture B; see also [glCopyTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCopyTexImage2D.xhtml), [glCopyTexSubImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCopyTexSubImage2D.xhtml)).

You could also do Geometry LOD (more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail_(computer_graphics))).